# Retrieving the proprietary blobs from Android for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

I'm following the porting guide for my Samsung Galaxy Note GT-N7000.

I'm at the part where I need to get the proprietary files from cyanogenmod.

The wiki guide states:

> Tip: you can alternatively extract these binaries from the image
>   (which is essentially a .zip file containing, amongst others, these
>   binary files), but flashing it first helps as you can see if CM is
>   working properly in the device.

I already know CM works on the device, so I'd like to skip that step. But which files do I copy? That's not made clear.

Answer (score 3):

To extract the binary blobs, you have to first connect your device to your computer. Make sure adb detects your device.

Then, navigate to `device/samsung/n7000` in your build environment and run the "extract_files.sh" script. The script will then automatically find all the binary blobs on your device and copy them to `vendor/samsung/n7000/proprietary` using `adb pull`.

See [the full script](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_n7000/blob/cm-10.2/extract-files.sh) for more information.

Alternatively, if CM is currently not installed on the device, download the cyanogenmod .zip for your device from [here](http://get.cm/?device=n7000) and extract it. Assuming you have extracted the zip to ~/Downloads/ ,you now have to edit `extract_files.sh` in 
`device/samsung/n7000` and change the line

```
adb pull /$FILE $DEVICEBASE/$FILE
```

to

```
cp ~/Downloads/cm-10.2-<DATE>-NIGHTLY-n7000/$FILE $DEVICEBASE/$FILE
```

putting the right folder name of the extracted zip of course. Save the script and run it.

Comment: Thanks. I also had to disable the adb daemon and adb-wait-for-device stuff. I also had to modify the device/samsung/galaxys2-common/extract-files.sh file, because it was also called. There it did fail on the file "/sbin/cbd", though ...